# Display Categories,subCategories with one query mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My table structure is like as below

**Main Product Only Table**
This table contains categories, child categories and sub categories like as below

```
id  name  parent_id  link
-------------------------
1   ABC      0      dummy  -- Parent Category
2   DEF      1      dummy  -- Child category
3   GHI      1      dummy  -- Child category
4   JKL      0      dummy  -- Parent Category
5   MNO      4      dummy  -- Child category
6   PQR      4      dummy  -- Child category
7   STU      2      dummy  -- Sub category 
8   VWX      2      dummy  -- Sub category
9   YZA      3      dummy  -- Sub category
10  BCA      3      dummy  -- Sub category 
11  FED      5      dummy  -- Sub category
12  IHG      5      dummy  -- Sub category 
13  LKJ      6      dummy  -- Sub category
```

Below is one more table which handles **products specifications and specifications are only for Sub Categories not for parent or childCat**

```
id  pid(fk of id in above table) img specifications
---------------------------------------------------
 1              7                dummy   dummy
 2              8                dummy   dummy
 3              9                dummy   dummy
 4              10               dummy   dummy
 ... so on
```

Now i want to display products like as on one page (Parent Category page)

```
Child Category ~ Name
SUBcat1(name~img)  SUBcat2(name~img)  SUBcat3(name~img)

.. so on
```

I have tried it using INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN but nothing seems to work.
Query i tried

```
$querychildcat = "select m.*,sp.* from `main_pr` m INNER JOIN 
p_speci sp ON (m.id = sp.pid) where m.`parent_id` = '1'";
```

Comment: Can you give exact output of query you want. I mean the columns with sample data. I see u hav given eg for it but it wud b great, if you give it as output of query like first sample for product.

Comment: @AbhayChauhan ... Sample data is given already... u want me to provide actual data???

Comment: Based on your above example can you please show sample response also. Inner join will not work because 0 is not there in your specification table try left join

Comment: left join also not work as parentid i pass is dynamic and is of parent category..